# Using same unpacked tarball to configure to install software into multiple different spots on server

Tags: linux, compiling, configure

Working on rebuilding some AWS linux servers. I see my company's server has Apache Portable Runtime (APR) downloaded within our Apache webserver instance as well as Tomcat.

What are the implications of configuring to install into multiple different locations/softwares, such as APR into Tomcat and Apache webserver?

If I run `./configure --prefix=/opt/tomcat/` and then another `./configure --prefix=/opt/apache2/` I see it downloaded the packages in those places.

Is this okay to do? Are there issues with doing this?

I see this done on the old servers where openSSL is also downloaded within apache and tomcat, and I'm assuming it was done with this same approach. But just want to get a good explanation as to the why this either okay or bad practice.

Comment: that is not "downloading into", that is "configuring to install into".

Comment: Okay understood. So is this a normal practice? I'm slightly newer to compiling software from source, but the server software was all compiled from source. So is it okay configuring to install into multiple locations on a server? Just want to make sure before I do it.

Comment: It very much isn't normal practice, for the reasons described in the answer, and unless you for some reason need two *different* versions of the same piece of software it's not a terribly good idea either, although it's not impossible as long as you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, yes. That's kind of the point of the prefix! However, when then running these servers, you need to make sure to adjust `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and other environment variables accordingly, so that the libraries and executables are actually taken from the different prefixes.

Also, installing the *same* binaries in two places makes little sense (aside from storage, and administrative headaches, it doesn't cost something): You could just run the one server with different configurations. How that works depends on the individual service.

But it's honestly a bit strange to compile such standard software yourself, unless you *know* why you need to do that. Especially in the server/cloud world, you'd usually just have a single service, installed as plainly as possible, and if you need two instances of the same service for some reason, you'd put both of them in containers, only sharing the relevant data directories with the host system.

So, this question feels like you should figure out the following things

1. What are these services actually doing?
2. Why are they built from source, and why do you need two separate installatios?
3. What resources would both instances necessarily share – for example, two webservers can't both answer to TCP port 80 on the same IP address, so that wouldn't work. Two different Tomcat applications could still want to share one database; that'd be fine. But if they both try to write to the same log file, things would go bad pretty quickly
4. In the context on anything on AWS, why aren't the two service instances not isolated from each other in a container each?